# I want to add swip left animation like tinder and slides up animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-animation

1. Back Button - should be an animation where the previous card slides up on top of current card
2. Pass Button - is simply like a swipe left animation like Tinder
   Just like that
   [animation1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQch7.gif)   --> Back Button
   [animation2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82z5j.gif)   -->pass button
   I have successfully change image mean when pass button pressed then change image to second image and when back button pressed then changed to previous image but cannot animate them like above given.
   I will be very thankful if anyone do that for me

```
 bool _isFirstImage = true;
//Backbutton
 void _onBackButtonTap() {

    Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
      if (!mounted) return;
      setState(() {
        _isFirstImage = true;
      });
    });
  }
//passbutton
  void _onPassButtonTap() {

    Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
      if (!mounted) return;
      setState(() {
        _isFirstImage = false;
      });
    });
  }
```

Simple UI

```
 Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Container(
              height: context.height*0.68,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                image:  DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(   //image path
                      _isFirstImage?"assets/images/image.jpeg":"assets/images/imageQ.jpeg"
                  ),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),

              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, bottom: 16),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      //User name
                      Visibility(
                        visible: _isHidden,  //visibility control due to some issue in UI
                        child: const Text("Jessica, 24",style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 30,
                            color: Colors.white
                        ),),
                      ),
                      //space
                      SizedBox(height: context.height*0.02,),
                      //Location
                      Visibility(
                        visible: _isHidden, //visibility control due to some issue in UI
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                          child: Material(
                            elevation: 4,
                            child: Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                              width: context.width*0.37,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: const Color(0xFF485354),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                              ),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                children: [
                                  const Icon(
                                    Icons.location_on,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    size: 30,
                                  ),
                                  const Text(
                                    'New York',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                      //Last Row with pass shoot back action
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          //  Pass action
                          InkWell(
                            onTap:_onPassButtonTap,
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 50,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  const Text("",style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 29
                                  ),),
                                  const Text("Pass",style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black
                                  ),)
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          //Shoot Action
                          InkWell(
                              onTap:_onBasketballIconTap,
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                                      colors: [
                                        Color(0xFF2A64E5),
                                        Color(0xFF3264E4),
                                        Color(0xFF453CCA),
                                        Color(0xFF3A43AF),
                                        Color(0xFF4634B1),

                                      ],
                                    )
                                ),
                                child: CircleAvatar(
                                  radius: 60,
                                  backgroundColor:Color(0xFF6814CE),
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children:const [
                                      Text("",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 42,fontFamily: "Roboto",),)          ,
                                      Text("Shoot")
                                    ],
                                  ),

                                ),
                              )
                          ),
//Back Action
                          InkWell(
                            onTap:_onBackButtonTap,
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 50,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  const Text("",style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 29
                                  ),),
                                  const Text("Back",style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black
                                  ),)
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this demo code :

use **swipeable_card_stack: ^0.0.5** dependency

**SwipAppScreen.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stackoverflow_demo/class/card_view.dart';
import 'package:swipeable_card_stack/swipeable_card_stack.dart';

class SwipeAppScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SwipeAppScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SwipeAppScreen> createState() => _SwipeAppScreenState();
}

class _SwipeAppScreenState extends State<SwipeAppScreen> {
  int counter = 4;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //create a CardController
    SwipeableCardSectionController _cardController =
        SwipeableCardSectionController();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          // title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          SwipeableCardsSection(
            cardController: _cardController,
            context: context,
            //add the first 3 cards
            items: [
              CardView(text: "First card"),
              CardView(text: "Second card"),
              CardView(text: "Third card"),
            ],
            onCardSwiped: (dir, index, widget) {
              //Add the next card
              if (counter <= 20) {
                _cardController.addItem(CardView(text: "Card $counter"));
                counter++;
              }

              if (dir == Direction.left) {
                print('onDisliked ${(widget as CardView).text} $index');
              } else if (dir == Direction.right) {
                print('onLiked ${(widget as CardView).text} $index');
              } else if (dir == Direction.up) {
                print('onUp ${(widget as CardView).text} $index');
              } else if (dir == Direction.down) {
                print('onDown ${(widget as CardView).text} $index');
              }
            },
            enableSwipeUp: true,
            enableSwipeDown: true,
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                FloatingActionButton(
                  child: Icon(Icons.chevron_left),
                  onPressed: () => _cardController.triggerSwipeLeft(),
                ),
                FloatingActionButton(
                  child: Icon(Icons.chevron_right),
                  onPressed: () => _cardController.triggerSwipeRight(),
                ),
                FloatingActionButton(
                  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
                  onPressed: () => _cardController.triggerSwipeUp(),
                ),
                FloatingActionButton(
                  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                  onPressed: () => _cardController.triggerSwipeDown(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**card_view.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CardView extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  CardView({required this.text});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```